# Predefined google search through javascript function

Tags: javascript

I need to do a predefined Google Search through a javascript function, launched by a button in the page.

So I have tryed before with no sucess:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">     
  function googleSearch(quest){
   var googlefind = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + quest + " buy Blu-Ray DVD";
   window.open(googlefind);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Buy this Anime Now!" onclick="googleSearch("Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood");">
</body>
</html>
```

Does somebody can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `escape()` to `googlefind` in your function, and changed the keywords to be in single quotes in your `onclick`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
 function googleSearch(quest){
  var googlefind = quest + " buy Blu-Ray DVD";
  window.open("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + escape(googlefind));
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Buy this Anime Now!" onclick="googleSearch('Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood');">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome, you did it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Also, keep in mind that some browsers will not like the `script` tag the way it's currently defined. I'd change to `type='text/javascript` instead of `language='JavaScript'` like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function googleSearch(quest){
  var googlefind = quest + " buy Blu-Ray DVD";
  window.open("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + googlefind);
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Buy this Anime Now!" onclick="googleSearch('Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood');" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace double quotes with single quotes in passing parameter
onclick="googleSearch('Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood')